# Can VBA code run after an application is closed?

Tags: vba, outlook, background-process

I am using the ItemAdd event to watch for new Outlook emails. Does this event work while the application is closed?

Currently, my macro launches upon initial startup using the "Application_Startup()" event, and then initializes a class module containing a sub routine that is trigged with the "ItemAdd" event. If I close Outlook, will this macro still be watching for a new "ItemAdd" event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not - the event is fired by the application only, so no application - no event.

Keep in mind that if this is a cached profile, these events will fire on application startup when the cached mailbox (OST) is updated. You can also work around this by processing all unread emails on startup (assuming they stay unread). Or you can persist the `MailItem.ReceivedTime` property of your last processed message and process all emails newer than that on startup.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I had thought about using the timestamp from when I last closed the application, and then processing all items with a received time after that point, provided the application class has that property.

Comment: Last processed item time is better than application closing time: the local clock can be off.